# Using INotify interface in single modal for Blazor and Maui

Tags: modal-dialog, blazor, inotifypropertychanged, maui

I want to write a single modal which is going to use in Blazor App and Maui App.
I am little bit confused regarding Implement INotify Interface Because Blazor do not need INotify Interface to be Implemented in its modal but Maui need.
so here is my question

1. Does is it good practise to use Single modal in Maui and Blazor App ?
2. By using INotify interface for blazor is going to side effect or bad performace ?
3. What is good Practise to use single modal in both Blazor and DotNet Maui ?

Note : I am already aware of DotNet Maui For Blazor but it is not realated to my question.

Comment: I use INotifyPropertyChanged in blazor services all the time. You may have to combine it with `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` depending on the thread its called from.

Comment: how do you avoid calling NotifyPropertyChanged many times if multiple properties are setted sequentially?